# How do I extract JWT claims passed through APIM?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, azure-api-management

I have the following Controller in .NET:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public TestController() { }

    [HttpGet("Test")]
    public ActionResult<string> Test() 
    {
        string? subject = User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
        if (subject == null) 
        {
            return NotFound("Claim 'sub' not found.");
        }
        return Ok($"Subject: {subject}");
    }
}
```

Default Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I published this application to Azure Web App, and then uploaded it to Azure API Management (APIM). In APIM, I have the following XML Policies:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="WebApp_web-app-hermie" />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" require-expiration-time="false" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key><my-key></key>
            </issuer-signing-keys>
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="sub" match="all">
                    <value>1234567890</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I got the JWT from jwt.io, where:

Header

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Payload

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

Verify signature

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
<my-key>
)
```

and secret base64 encoded is checked.

Here is the result:

```
Claim 'sub' not found.
```

The authentication works, but not the extraction of the claims. APIM is doing all the validation, so I don't believe I need to do that in code, all I need to do is extract JWT information and return it. However, that is not working. Can anyone help me how to extract JWT claims that are passed through APIM?

Comment: At least you need to fix your code and return NotFound.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#authentication-concepts

Answer (score 0):

I think to populate the User property, you should at least decorate your action method with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

This attribute will help the framework determine which action needs authentication, and therefore authenticate a request forwarded to this action. I think this will fix your issue